# commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{S_n}$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find the commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{S_n}$. I already know the answer is $\mathbb{A_n}$, but I am trying to prove it.
From this link
[here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf), on page 2, I know that one of the sets of generators is $(12)$ and $(2345...n)$.
Thus, $\mathbb{S_n}=<(12),(234...n)>$ and that means $S_n'=<[(12),(234...n)]>$\

I now calculate $[(12),(234...n)]=(12)^{-1} (234...n)^{-1} (12)(234...n)=(12)(n  ... 432)(12)(1234...n)=(21n)$
But I know that $\mathbb{A_n}=<(rsk) | 1 \leq k \leq n, k \neq r,s>$.

So I woul need $<(21k) | 1 \leq k \leq n, k \neq 2,1>$ in order for it to work...
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commutator subgroup is a *normal* subgroup of $S_n.$ That means that if it contains an element, it contains all elements conjugate to it. Any pair of $3$-cycles are conjugate, so if your mysterious commutator subgroup contains one $3$-cycle it contains all of them, and now you need the fact that the three-cycles generate $A_n$ (which you already know).

Comment: Is the commutator subgroup G' of a group G alwayss a normal subgroup of G, or is it just for $S_n$?

Comment: Yes, it is always normal.